# UIAlertController shown on BarButtonItem not centered properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar, uialertcontroller

I am using the following code to show the UIAlertController on a toolBarButtonItem,

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }]];     

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete Selected Accounts" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [Utility showAlertWithTitle:nil message:DELETE_ACCOUNT delegate:self tag:1 buttons:@[@"Cancel", @"Delete"]];
    }]];
    alertController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.moreButtonItem;
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The alertController shown using this code appears right sided not centered. I want the alertController to appear exactly at center position over the toolBarButtonItem.

Comment: Try by using `alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect` and `alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView`  instead of barbutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding below code

```
 alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = senderView; //your view
 alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = senderView.bounds; //your view
 alertController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your help.